# CSS tabs to grow with content

Tags: css, html, tabs, size

I'm having a little problem with my CSS tabs. The thing is, the content area does not grow according to the content inside it. Here's the css code:

```
.tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 400px; 
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}



.tab1 {
  float: left;
}
.tab2 {
  float: left;
}
.tab3 {
  float: left;
}


.tab1 label {
  background: white; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-right:2px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;

}

.tab2 label {
  background: white; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-right:2px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
   border-top-right-radius: 15px;
   border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
}

.tab3 label {
  background: white; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc;  
  margin-right:2px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
   border-top-right-radius: 15px;
   border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
}




.tab1 [type=radio] {
  display: none;  
}
.tab2 [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}
.tab3 [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}



  .content1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: #936;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}

  .content2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: #09C;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}

  .content3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: #990;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}



   .tab1 [type=radio] ~ label:hover
{
background: #936;
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
}
   .tab2 [type=radio] ~ label:hover
{
background: #09C;
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
}
   .tab3 [type=radio] ~ label:hover
{
background: #990;
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
}




.tab1 [type=radio]:checked ~ label
{
    background: #936;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tab2 [type=radio]:checked ~ label
{
    background: #09C;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tab3 [type=radio]:checked ~ label
{
    background: #990;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}





[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content1 {
  z-index: 1;

}
 [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content2 {
  z-index: 1;

}
 [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content3 {
  z-index: 1;

}
```

(sorry it's too long) and then the HTML one:

```
<div id="page-wrap">
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab1">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked="checked" />
    <label for="tab-1">One</label>

    <div class="content1">
      <p>Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here.
      Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here.
      Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here.
      Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here.
      Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here.
      Some content here. Some content here. Some content here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab2">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1" /> <label for="tab-2">Two</label>

    <div class="content2">
      Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here.
      Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here.
      Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here.
      Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here.
      Some content here. Some content here. Some content here.<br />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab3">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1" /> <label for="tab-3">Three</label>

    <div class="content3">
      <p>Stuff for Tab Three</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried `overflow: both;` inside `.content` but that gave me scrollbars, I want the content area itself to grow. I even tried to call `.clear {clear: both;}` but that didn't seem to work well too.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks :)

Comment: Its a little difficult to understand what you want. Have you tried making a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to help elaborate?

Comment: I actually made one myself to try and test this and find a solution but had no luck. Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/UDDkU/

Comment: Please, please, please indent your HTML.

Comment: When using absolute positioning it is best to use either `top` or `bottom` + `left` or `right` but not all four at once.

Comment: @NickBewley: Guess it's done. I was meaning to have the tab content area grow along with the content in it, i.e. dynamic. Just learnt about jsfiddle, useful tool, will give it a try if im in need of more things later.

Comment: @CyleHunter : Thanks for giving it a try though.

Comment: @11684 :  I'm sorry first time posting here and the guide to indent HTML said use the {} and that's just what I did.

Comment: @Jrod : Not very good with CSS but I'll remember that. Thanks.

Comment: @user1886728 that only works if it has already been indented. The thing is, SO removers that whitespace unless you use {}. So you probably misunderstood the Guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  .content1 {
    position:absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: #936;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    clear:both;
}

  .content2 {
   position:absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: #09C;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    clear:both;
}
  .content3 {
  position:absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: #990;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    clear:both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UDDkU/1/

It still needs some work to show and hide the correct tabs but your overflow problem is fixed.  If you want all the tabs to have the same width you will need to add one.

**UPDATE**

Here is an updated version with condensed css and completed tabs.

http://jsfiddle.net/UDDkU/20/